# DRY functional programming: how to avoid the same line of code in different higher order functions

Tags: python, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Imagine we have the following setup (let it be written in Python, the language is not essential though):

```
def f1_provider(vars, degree):
    dim1, dim2, dim3 = set_dims(vars, degree)
    def f1(*args1):
        # ...
        # use vars and dims
        # ...
    return f1

def f2_provider(vars, degree):
    dim1, dim2, dim3 = set_dims(vars, degree)
    def f2(*args2):
        # ...
        # use vars and dims
        # ...
    return f2

def f3_provider(vars, degree):
    dim1, dim2, dim3 = set_dims(vars, degree)
    def f3(*args3):
        # ...
        # use vars and dims
        # ...
    return f3

# then use them somewhere:

def f1_user():
    # ...
    f1 = f1_provider(vars1, degree1)
    # ...
def f2_f3_user():
    # ...
    f2 = f2_provider(vars2, degree2)
    f3 = f3_provider(vars2, degree2)
    # ...
```

As you can see, this design is not so good at least because:

- The `dim1, dim2, dim3 = set_dims(vars, degree)` line is being repeated over and over again. I might say the same about signatures of these provider methods - but let's not be so captious, I can bear with that at least :).
- The `set_dims` function is applied one extra time: it's result is already known during the `f2_provider(vars2, degree2)` call. However, it runs once again during the third provider's call.

How can this be reworked in a functional  way?

If we were in OOP one should have introduced a class like `GeneralProvider`, put the `set_dims` call in its constructor and made these providers public methods. Nope, not so interesting :).

Comment: Well, if you require that the call be `f3_provider(vars2, degree2)`, then there is just no magical way to get those dims unless you call `get_dims` (again). Persistance from a previous call with the same `vars2, degree2` seems not to be in your acceptance criteria, as you want a functional approach. So that marks the end of options then.

Comment: @trincot, actually, I didn't say I want the call to be exactly `f3_provider(vars2, degree2)`. I only want not to repeat myself and not to make the computer repeat itself. Now I believe there are some options using partial applications or sth like that, though it doesn't sound very pleasant (as least I don't see how it can be made pleasant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a workaround, though it's quite ugly. But it should work, in theory). I'll still be waiting for better solutions!

```
def f1_provider(vars_, dim1, dim2, dim3):
    def f1(*args1):
        # ...
        # use vars_ and dims
        # ...
    return f1

def f2_provider(vars_, dim1, dim2, dim3):
    def f2(*args2):
        # ...
        # use vars_ and dims
        # ...
    return f2

def f3_provider(vars_, dim1, dim2, dim3):
    def f3(*args3):
        # ...
        # use vars_ and dims
        # ...
    return f3


def general_provider(providers, vars_, degree):
    dim1, dim2, dim3 = set_dims(vars_, degree)
    return [f_prov(vars_, dim1, dim2, dim3) for f_prov in providers]

# then use them somewhere:

def f1_user():
    # ...
    f1 = general_provider((f1_provider,), vars1, degree1)
    # ...
def f2_f3_user():
    # ...
    f2, f3 = general_provider((f2_provider, f3_provider), vars2, degree2)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this appropriate solution for you?

```py
def f1_provider(vars, degree, *dims):
    def f1(*args1):
        # ...
        # use vars and dims
        # ...
    return f1

def f2_provider(vars, degree, *dims):
    def f2(*args2):
        # ...
        # use vars and dims
        # ...
    return f2

def f3_provider(vars, degree, *dims):
    def f3(*args3):
        # ...
        # use vars and dims
        # ...
    return f3

# then use them somewhere:

def f1_user():
    # ...
    dim1, dim2, dim3 = set_dims(vars1, degree1)
    f1 = f1_provider(vars1, degree1, dim1, dim2, dim3)
    # ...
def f2_f3_user():
    # ...
    dim1, dim2, dim3 = set_dims(vars2, degree2)
    f2 = f2_provider(vars2, degree2, dim1, dim2, dim3)
    f3 = f3_provider(vars2, degree2, dim1, dim2, dim3)
    # ...
```

Comment: I'm afraid that won't do. While it solves the second problem mentioned, it introduces even more boilerplate, I think. We'll now have to duplicate all these long arguments sets. But what's worse, it breaks the level of abstraction: `f_user`'s don't need to know about `dim`s and `set_dims`. Anyway, thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Thank you for the question, you made me think